# Is it possible to use Blending modes with CSS?

Tags: css, image, browser

Is it possible to use *Blending modes* in the browser?
Do I need to use vendor prefix? Is it very compatible?

I have been waiting for this for so long and I can't find more info about this.

Comment: First result:http://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Comment: Compatability - http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/graphics/blendmodes/browser-support/

Comment: @NicoO hehe but like I said; Published February 28, 2014 - Is old news ;)

Comment: sadly it's still a draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blending and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode . I don't know which browsers you want to support, but from this information i would say: No, you can not use it for production now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all browser have accepted Blend-Modes yet. You may check your browser compatibility here

http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/graphics/blendmodes/browser-support/

It is recommendable to go with third party applications for this as through CSS it may not give you the desired results. However in CSS, we have three new properties, i.e.

```
background-blend-mode, mix-blend-mode, and isolation
```

You may refer the website below for more information:

http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/